# How to route app with multiple subdomain using Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have developed an application using Laravvel-5.8.

I have developed the application for just a single company whereby each table have a company_id derived from the company table as shown below:

```
class Company extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'companies';
  protected $fillable = [
     'id',
     'company_name',
     'subdomain',   
  ];
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{
  protected $fillable = [
   'name',
   'company_id',
   'email',
  ];
}
```

and the route/web.php looks like this:

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => '/', 'uses' => 'IndexController@getLogin']);

Auth::routes();
Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->name('dashboard');

  // Config Module
  Route::group(['prefix' => 'config', 'as' => 'config.', 'namespace' => 'Config', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::resource('countries', 'ConfigCountriesController');
    Route::resource('nationalities', 'ConfigNationalitiesController');
});

 // HR Module
  Route::group(['prefix' => 'hr', 'as' => 'hr.', 'namespace' => 'Hr', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () { 
    Route::resource('designations', 'HrDesignationsController');
    Route::resource('departments', 'HrDepartmentsController');  
    Route::resource('employee_categories', 'HrEmployeeCategoriesController');

});
```

The main route is :

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => '/', 'uses' => 'IndexController@getLogin']);
```

which gives localhost:8888/myapp

config/app.php:

```
'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'localhost:8888/myapp'),
'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', null),
```

I'm asked to add sub-domains where each will see the data based on the company_id in each table

```
localhost:8888/myapp
localhost:8888/company1.myapp
localhost:8888/company2.myapp
```

All will use:

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => '/', 'uses' => 'IndexController@getLogin']);
```

After successful login will redirect to:

```
Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->name('dashboard');
```

Also each will only see it's data based on company_id

companies table:

```
id | company_name       |    subdomain
1  | Main               |
2  | Company1           |    company1
3  | Company2           |    company2

Main=>  localhost:8888/myapp
Company1=>localhost:8888/company1.myapp
Company2=>localhost:8888/company2.myapp
```

How do I modify:

```
route/web.php
config/app.php
```

to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to apply for most of the routes then using a middleware should be the best option, Also `localhost:8888/company1.myapp` is not what we can call as subdomain, subdomain will be like `{company_name}.myapp.com`

Comment: @bhucho- How do I now exempt {company_name}. for the main company and allow it just to use myapp.com

Comment: what is your original domain the localhost one or {company_name}.myapp.com ?

Comment: @bhucho - This is the original domainn:   localhost:8888/myapp   See it here: id | company_name       |    subdomain
1  | Main               |
2  | Company1           |    company1
3  | Company2           |    company2

Main=>  localhost:8888/myapp
Company1=>localhost:8888/company1.myapp
Company2=>localhost:8888/company2.myapp

Comment: one last question, is the company name static like company1, company2 you will insert maually or it is to be inserted from a db table ?

Comment: @bhucho - it comes from the table as show in my question (companies table:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods by which It can be done.

#### By Middleware

As per your question, login page urls can be `localhost:8888/myapp`, `localhost:8888/company1.myapp`, or `localhost:8888/company2.myapp`

Using middleware, we will keep the company name in the session using middleware. You can use it from session.

```
php artisan make:middleware VerifyDomain
```

will create a domain

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class VerifyDomain
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $domain == "myapp"; // your company app name
        $path = $request->getPathInfo(); // should return /company1.myapp or /company2.myapp or /myapp 
        if (strpos($path, ".") !== false) { // if path has dot.
            list($subdomain, $main) = explode('.', $path);
            if(strcmp($domain, $main) !== 0){
                abort(404); // if domain is not myapp then throw 404 page error
            }
        } else{
            if(strcmp($domain, $path) !== 0){
                abort(404); // if domain is not myapp then throw 404 page error
            }
            $subdomain = ""; // considering for main domain value is empty string.
        }
        
        $company = Company::where('company_name', $subdomain)->firstOrFail(); // if not found then will throw 404
        
        $request->session()->put('company_name', $company); //store it in session

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then add it to route middleware.
In your controller you can redirect to different dashboards as per the company names stored in session.

#### In route groups

```
Route::domain('localhost:8888/myapp')->group(function () {
   Route::get('/', function ($id) {
       //
   });
});

Route::domain('localhost:8888/{company_name}.myapp')->group(function () {
   Route::get('/', function ($company_name, $id) {
       $company = Company::where('company_name', $company_name)->firstOrFail();
       // send the value of $company to data to send different view data 
   });
});
```

Comment: Sorry for this last question. How do I now accomodate the various groups as shown in the question. For example:  Route::group(['prefix' => 'config', 'as' => 'config.', 'namespace' => 'Config', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {       and             Route::group(['prefix' => 'hr', 'as' => 'hr.', 'namespace' => 'Hr', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-groups, add it as key, value pair in route group

Comment: If you use middleware then add along with auth middleware, if a domain then you can directly add via domain key or as domain static function as shown above

Comment: how do I call or reference the middleware, VerifyDomain in Route in route/web.php

Comment: add it as value of array, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-middleware